# Angle for maximum range for projectile from elevation

Tags: kinematics, differentiation, projectile

A gun of muzzle speed v is situated at a height h above a horizontal plane. At what angle,should the gun be fired to get the maximum horizontal range.

I got R = ((vsinx+((v^2)sin^2x+2gh)^(1/2))vcosx)/g

I then equated dR/dx to be 0 and the maximum I could simplify it to was cot^2(2x)=(cos^2(2x)+4(g^2)(h^2)-4ghcos2x)/vsin^2(2x)+8ghvcos^2(x)

I think I have correctly simplified it but I cannot further simplify it and neither wolfram alpha or any other sites are helping me.
Please show an easier and elegant method to solve this or simplify the equation for x.

Comment: In $dR/dx=0$, get rid of the square roots (multiply through, isolate, and square). Then get rid of $\cos x$ in favor of $\sin x$. Avoid trig functions of $2x$. There will be an amazing cancellation of $\sin^6x$ and $\sin^4x$ terms, leaving a simple equation for $\sin^2x$.

Comment: Next time, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). No one wants to try to read equations like the ones you wrote.